# Auth::guard('admin')->user() returns NULL

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

My project is working fine on local server but when I deploy it to the production server my middleware is not working I'm using Guard to restrict authenticated user to access the pages but when I put my routes inside the group middleware It always return Unauthenticated...
Tried a lot of solution found online but nothing is useful so far...

```
Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->group(function () {

Route::get('notifications',Notifications::class);
```

});

````
       'web' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],
       'admin' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'admins',
       ],
     
   ],```
````

Comment: Have you run `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: yes I did, nothing changed

Answer (score -1):

Probably the problem is caused by the route group declaration.
Try declaring them like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function (){
 // If you haven't declared the controller path within web.php, declare the route like this
 Route::get('notifications', [App\Http\Controllers\Notifications::class, 'method_you_want']);
});
```

**EDIT: Livewire Controller Example**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\Ente;

class TableEnti extends Component
{
    public $enti = null;
    public $idt = null;
    public $markedRows = null;

    public function openModal(Request $request, $id){

        // Setting up the db connection ( this for multi-tenant app)
        if (null !== $request->get('throughMiddleware')) {
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        } else {
            //recupero l'id del tenant
            $this->connection = null;
            $this->idt = tenant('id');
        }

        //recupero lo specifico ente
        $ente = Ente::on($this->connection)->find($id);

        //$ente = $this->parseValues($ente);

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('open', ['ente' => $ente, 'idt' => $this->idt]);
        $this->markRow($id);

    }

    public function markRow($id){
        $this->markedRows = null;
        $this->markedRows = $id;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.table-enti')
        ->with('enti', $this->enti)
        ->with('idt', $this->idt)
        ->with('markedRows', $this->markedRows);
    }

    private function parseValues($ente)
    {
        $ente->codicefiscale = $ente->codicefiscale == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->codicefiscale;
        $ente->abilitato = $ente->abilitato == true ? 'SI' : 'NO';
        $ente->id_qualifica = $ente->id_qualifica == null ? 'Dato mancante' : Qualifica::on($this->connection)->find($ente->id_qualifica)->descrizione;
        $ente->ruolo = $ente->ruolo == 0 ? 'Admin' : 'Collaboratore';
        $ente->ufficio = $ente->ufficio == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->ufficio;
        $ente->indirizzo = $ente->indirizzo == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->indirizzo;
        $ente->id_comune = $ente->id_comune == null ? 'Dato mancante' : Comune::on($this->connection)->find($ente->id_comune)->denominazione_comune;
        $ente->id_provincia = $ente->id_provincia == null ? 'Dato mancante' : Provincia::on($this->connection)->find($ente->id_provincia)->nome;
        $ente->cap = $ente->cap == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->cap;
        $ente->cellulare = $ente->cellulare == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->cellulare;
        $ente->telefono = $ente->telefono == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->telefono;
        $ente->fax = $ente->fax == null ? 'Dato mancante' : $ente->fax;
        return $ente;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the route declaration already... also I'm using livewire that's why I haven't declared the ruote name. It's so frustrating because everything works on local server.. Is there any config should I check, Like in env or Authenticate.php.

Comment: Please if you can post your controller code and livewire code...i've used livewire only for one project because I didn't like how it worked and it was causing problems for the app.

Comment: `class Notifications extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
 
        $notifications = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->unreadNotifications;
    
        return view('livewire.notifications',compact('notifications'));
    }`

Comment: It's first project in livewire also...

Comment: Actually I'm not able to access auth()->user() details on my production server... anywhere.. Initially I thought might the issue is with livewire but I'm not able to get authenticated user anywhere..but this works fine on local xampp server

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that you declare everything in the render method, it should just call the correct view and then pass the notifications variable to it.
Edited the answer above with an example of a Livewire controller.

Comment: Thankyou, really appreciate your help...
I'm passing the data based on logged in user... But in this I'm not able to retrieve the logged in user...

Comment: always returning null.. I thought there might be issue with my .env config , as It was mentioned In some other questions to correct APP_URL...

Comment: the issue might be with the auth guard I'm using...or any related config...